# Help me with my Steam Downloads

Tags: steam

I want to play Ark, I bought it and want to download it. But. Garry's Mod is doing a download. But the Garry's Mod download will not start at all. If I press resume, it will say it's doing it but not doing anything at all. Is there a way to switch my Ark download from the Steam? So I can have Ark downloading instead of the stupid broken Garry's mod one. Without deleting any of my game data?

Answer (score 6):

You can re-arrange queue of download, and cancel the update/download of Gmod. You can do this by right-clicking on any game that is downloading, then clicking **Manage Downloads**. An alternative way of accessing Download manager is clicking the Downloading sign on the bottom of the Library section.

[image]

You will see Gmod downloading on the top. Click the pause button. Then click the up-arrow on Ark below to initiate downloading.

[image]

If I wanted to pause Starbound, and update Unturned, I would click pause on top-right and then the up-arrow on unturned to start the download.

Comment: Actually, just clicking the up arrow should change the order.

Comment: @Powerlord I see. It does say **Download Now** on arrow hover